# Getting a unique token from a page using CURL

Tags: javascript, php, curl

And so I setup some security in my application by generating a unique token everytime the page reloads, so there won't be a spam-clicking

Lets say I set it up like this:

```
<a href="#" data="{'token':'2434jasfdsfa435', 'id' : 'foo'}">button</a>
```

If I try using curl to hack my own application, what should I do to get that unique token so I can loop through on clicking that button and sending my data over and over like

```
while(true){
 $token = ????
 $id = 'foo';
 $useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://domain.com/ajax.php?token=$token&id=$id; 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
 $res = curl_exec ($ch) ;


 curl_close($ch);

 sleep(6);
}
```

Comment: That depends on how you implemented your _security_. What happens if a user requests without a valid token? Can you post the respective part of your logic? (I assume it's PHP)

Comment: You need to parse the HTML (you can use Simple HTML DOM Parser library for this), find the anchor, get the `data` attribute, parse the token and ID out of it (it's _almost_ like JSON, but not quite, so you can't use `json_decode()`).

Comment: @Barmar This would only work if you don't need a token to access the page in the first place.

Comment: @MCL True, but somehow ordinary users are able to access the page without having a token yet, so it must be possible.